# module 'torch' has no attribute 'dml'

Tags: python, pytorch, directml

I want to run Stable Diffusion on my PC with an integrated AMD graphics card (Vega 11 in Ryzen 5 2400G).  The webui-user.bat command line arguments contain

> "--autolaunch --precision full --no-half --skip-torch-cuda-test
> --opt-sub-quad-attention --lowvram --lowram --disable-nan-check --backend directml".

What should I do?

Used the instruction from [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-pytorch-windows) , but it didn't help.  When running

> `AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'dml'

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by deleting the venv folder and running with `--use-directml` in the args.